# Custom Query Arguments

Tags: customization, query, tax-query

I want to run a query base on the following $args.  My question that how to pass variable number of arrays to tax_query as currently i have two arrays within tax_query it can be 1 , 3 or 5 and so on. Is there any possibility ?

```
$args = array (
            'posts_per_page' => 10,
            'tax_query' => array(
                'relation' => 'OR',
                array(
                    'taxonomy' => $Tax[0],
                    'field' => 'slug',
                    'terms' => array( $Tag )
                ),
                array(
                    'taxonomy' => $Tax[1],
                    'field' => 'slug',
                    'terms' => array( $Tag )

                )
            ),
            'order' => 'DESC'

        );
```

Comment: you mean something like `$args['tax_query'][] = array(...` ?

Answer (score 0):

```
/**
 * Define a new function that uses $args and wp_parse_args()
 */
function explain_parse_args( $args ) {
    $defaults = array (
        'text' => 'wp_parse_args() merges $args into $defaults',
        'before' => "",
        'after' => " \n",
        'echo' => TRUE
    );

    // Parse incomming $args into an array and merge it with $defaults
    $args = wp_parse_args( $args, $defaults );

    // OPTIONAL: Declare each item in $args as its own variable i.e. $type, $before.
    extract( $args, EXTR_SKIP );

    $output = $before . $text . $after;

    if (!$echo) 
        return $output;

    echo $output;
}

/**
 * Run our new function using the defaults (no $args)
 * This would print out: 
 *  wp_parse_args() merges $args into $defaults
 */
explain_parse_args();

/**
 * Run the function with some options overriden with an array
 * This would echo the output with the modified text and before arguments:
 *  A better explanation
 */
explain_parse_args( array (
    'text' => "A better explanation",
    'before' => ""
) );

/**
 * We can also pass in URL-style string-query and it will be converted
 * This would set $args['echo'] to 1 and $args['text'] to 0 
 */
explain_parse_args( 'echo=1&text=0' );
```

Comment: I think you have not got my question I am just asking how to add one or more array to tax_query dynamically.                                                       Currently there are two array one is array(
                    'taxonomy' => $Tax[1],
                    'field' => 'slug',
                    'terms' => array( $Tag )

                )                                                                        I want to add as many as i like but dynamically.

Comment: It has been solved with custom query......

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I'd do it:

```
$args = array (
  'posts_per_page' => 10,
  'order' => 'DESC'
);
$tax_query = array('relation' => 'OR');

for($i=0;$i<count($Tax),$i++){
  array_push($tax_query, array(
    'taxonomy' => $Tax[$i],
    'field' => 'slug',
    'terms' => array( $Tag )
  ));
}

$args['tax_query'] = $tax_query;
```

Using shorthand array-braces might be more legible:

```
$args = [
  'posts_per_page' => 10,
  'order' => 'DESC'
];

$tax_query = ['relation' => 'OR'];

for($i=0;$i<count($Tax),$i++){
  $tax_query[] = [
    'taxonomy' => $Tax[$i],
    'field' => 'slug',
    'terms' => array( $Tag )  
  ];
}

$args['tax_query'] = $tax_query;
```